# Reverse Prime Number

Tags: c++, numbers, calculation

I want to check if a number `a` and its reverse are prime or not.
The number must be read from keyboard.

The restrictions are :

- 1 ≤ a ≤ 2000000000
- `a` does not have the last digit 0

Here are some example inputs for `a` and the expected output

```
Input  Output
5      Yes
112    No
17     Yes
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    int RevNum =0;
    int Remain;
    int i=2;
    int prim = 1;
    int a_inainte = a;
    if ( (1 <= a && a <= 2000000000) && (a % 10 != 0) )
    {
            while(a != 0)
            {
                Remain = a % 10;
                RevNum = RevNum * 10 + Remain;
                a /= 10;
            }

            if (i < RevNum && i< a_inainte)
            {
                if (RevNum % i == 0 || a_inainte % i ==0)
                    prim = 0;
                ++i;
            }

            if (RevNum == 1 && a_inainte == 1)
                prim = 0;
            if (prim == 1)
                cout<<"DA";
            else
                cout<<"NU";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"NU";
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

I'm not sure why but everything in codeblocks seems to be ok but I still don`t get all points on a test(that's because compiler check code with more numbers).

Comment: It may be helpful if you added the test case that failed.

Comment: ***because compiler check code with more numbers*** Not sure if I guessed correctly what you meant by that.

Comment: @drescherjm https://imgur.com/a/LohfFKj

Comment: What is the reverse of a number?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic I believe in this case it's meant to indicate reversing the order of the digits.

Comment: It does not say what test 6 is so the image does not really help.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic    a=132 and its reverse is 321

Comment: @drescherjm No,it does not say.That`s why im confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a short function to check the primality of a number.

I've based the below code on the [pseudocode code from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode). The explanation of how this works is explained more in depth there, but essentially to test if a number `n` is prime you need to check that it is not divisible by any prime number `i` from `2` to `sqrt(n)`.

```
bool is_prime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;
    else if (n <= 3)
        return true;
    else if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
        return false;

    int i = 5;
    while (i*i <= n) {
         if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)
             return false;
         i += 6;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can check if `a` is prime just by calling

```
is_prime(a);
```

To check if the reverse is prime you will need to calculate the reveres of `a`. I found an interesting approach by Arslan7041 [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/198781/#msg951652) which works pretty much the same as what you are already doing:

```
int reverse(int x) {
    bool negative = false;
    if(x < 0) {
        negative = true;
        x = -x;
    }

    int reversed = 0;
    while(x > 0) {
        reversed = reversed*10 + x%10;
        x /= 10;
    }

    if(negative) reversed = -reversed;

    return reversed;
}
```

And now you can check if the reverse of `a` is prime with the following:

```
 is_prime(reverse(a));
```

Lastly we can address your special two restrictions with a simple if statement.

```
if (1 <= a && a <= 2000000000 && a % 10 != 0 
    && is_prime(a) && is_prime(reverse(a)) ) {
    cout << "DA\n";
}
```

Comment: That was hard for me because i didn't reach this course yet.But,i dont know why i understand this very well.

Comment: I think this is a good use of functions and code self documentation. Two concepts that should help others who are just beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to verify if a or reverse of a is a prime by dividing all the integers less than or equal to these number a, but in the code you are only dividing by i = 2 and i = 3. You must iterate over i.

Comment: Hmm, now I am surprised that the original code got that much credit for a very wrong (but fast) prime determination.

Comment: @drescherjm as a TA I once ran up against a test rig used to grade students on an assignment. The students were expected to use a linked list to do arithmetic on big numbers, the point of the assignment being fight your way through a linked list. The tester had only one computation out of 20 that went outside 64 bit, so the bulk of the class was getting great and identical marks by not producing a linked list at all and just doing regular arithmetic on `long long`s. One would think that the grading system would have been designed to test what the assignment was supposed to teach, but no.